# Sql statement with expression in group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question about one sql statement for my mysql db. I have a table with the following columns :-

```
sender_id | receiver_id | content | dateAndTime
```

As you understand I would like to implement sending messages between users. I want to select the last message(doesn't matter sent or received) with every user. Something like the messages in facebook. I guess that I should use expression in group by if it is possible but I would like to see your opinion how I should do it. Thanks!

Comment: You can check my solution here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb646/7

Comment: @user1107922, You have a lot of questions and only some of them has accepted answers. Can you accept some answers or close question?

Answer (score 0):

For This kind of purpose, your field `dateAndTime` is must be date-time type.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY dateAndTime DESC
```

You can retrieve latest data using this descending order.

Comment: But this will return all messages ordered by date. I want only the last message for every user.

Comment: user mean sender or receiver?

Comment: I have the current logged user id. I would like to select for this user id the last message with every other person. So in some cases my user id will be sender_id in other receiver_id.

Comment: whenever user sends a message, other user receives it. so do you need result for sender and receiver both ?

Comment: @unknown the op has explained this. The OP wants the last message associated with each and every user, regardless of whether it was sent or received

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT C.ID, T.content, T.dateAndTime FROM T JOIN
(
SELECT ID, MAX(dateAndTime) 'last' FROM
(
SELECT sender_id 'ID', content, dateAndTime FROM T
UNION
SELECT receiver_id 'ID', content, dateAndTime FROM T
) B
GROUP BY ID
) C
WHERE T.dateAndTime = C.last AND (T.sender_id = C.ID OR T.receiver_id = C.ID)
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have a 'users' table, and your stated table named 'mytable' you could:

```
select users.id,mytable.content, MAX(mytable.dateAndTime) as date 
from users join mytable 
on users.id = mytable.sender_id 
or users.id = mytable.receiver_id 
group by users.id, mytable.content, date
```

The max function will keep only the latest date from each group generated by the group by

EDIT: try this instead

```
select users.id, mytable.content, mytable.dateAndTime
from users join mytable 
on users.id = mytable.sender_id 
or users.id = mytable.receiver_id
where mytable.dateAndTime = (select max(t.dateAndTime) from mytable as t where t.receiver_id = users.id or t.sender_id = users.id)
```

Comment: I haven't tried but I'm pretty sure this won't work. You're missing several columns in your GROUP BY clause as only mytable.dateAndTime is in an aggregate function. Even if you add all other columns you would get the wrong result because all rows are unique respective to their entire content.

Comment: lol agree with first part, answered too fast; don't agree with second part though

Comment: But the edited answer returns all messages ordered by date for every person. I would like only the last message for every person.

Comment: @user1107922 could you share the error? (just editted again so try now)